# Move data from a MATLAB program to python

Tags: python, matlab

I am fairly new to programming, and started programming in python 3. The data I want to analyze have already been processed in a matlab program, and I need to export them. I don't know anything about matlab, and after searching the web I came up with this:

```
fileID = fopen('VarA.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%.10f \n',data_1(:,1));
fclose(fileID);

fileID = fopen('varB.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%.10f \n',data_1(:,2));
fclose(fileID);
```

This gives me 2 .txt files with x and y coordinates respectively. I have about 1000 strings (which each contains about 10k datapoints), so this seems like an awful way to do this.

My question is then; how can I export these datasets with an efficient code? For instance: I am writing a dataset to 2 different .txt files which separates the 2 variables, instead of a hash saved in 1 file.

Comment: This is phrased as a set of statements, not a question. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: Are you going to install and use `numpy` and `scipy`?  Or just Python?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in exporting a lot of structured numerical data, i recommend you use the HDF5 functions in matlab to write these, and the corresponding python library to read these.

To simplify the code you showed there, read about dlmwrite in the matlab help.

The way you choose (or via dlmwrite) may sound awful in the beginning, but very often will not really have an impact on the performance.

Comment: Or even simpler, use `save` with the option `-v7.3` which creates a gzip compressed HDF5 file.

Comment: If you install the `h5py` library, you also need `numpy`.  `scipy` has a `loadmat` that can read `.mat` files.

Comment: The choice between using a .mat file  and an explicitly constructed HDF5 file depends mainly on whether a more specific control over the format is desired. If that is not the case, then using a .mat file (as suggested in both comments) is an appropriate solution.